# Копирование значения(не формулу) и удаление старого

Tags: google-apps-script

У меня есть парсер который идет по ссылкам в столбце "A" примерно 100 000 ссылок
в google таблицах и вытаскивает мне в столбец "B" наименование товара.
Суть в том, что когда запросы в google таблицах достигают 50 + - то пишется надпись, "что много запросов". По этому надо старые наименования которые уже получили куда то переносить и удалять их.
Проще говоря
столбец А - тут ссылки
столбец В - тут код который вытаскивает наименование товара
Мне необходимо чтобы в столбце В сканировался весь столбец с 1 до 100000 например и находил последнюю заполненную строку(с формулой) и наименованием , далее именно значение копировалось в столбец С по этому же индексу (номеру строки) а из столбца В где была формула и наименование значение удалялось.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на вашу таблицу, т.к. не хватает информации.
Как выглядят ссылки в столбце "А"? Какой код в столбце "В"?
Насколько я поняла задачу, это не сложно.